# getting file category in powershell script

Tags: powershell

I am very new to powershell script.  I have text file which contain sone sharepath(eg:\INTBMCELB\Abbott ADD HR Finance,\INTBMCELB\Abbott ADD HR Finance_VSS  etc).
 I read all the path in text file and the folders in each path, the details of folders  loaded in csv file. currently i have a field named size in csv file. i need to add one more field  called 'file category'.file category field shows as (tiny, small,large etc) based on file size as follow.

Tiny (0- 10KB), Small (10-100 KB), Medium (100 KB – 1 MB), Large (1-16MB), Huge (16-128 MB), Gigantic (>128 MB).

adding my current script below. how can check file size as above and included under new field.

```
$infile = 'C:\Users\417193\Desktop\MyShareBatch\SharePaths.txt'
$outdir = 'C:\Users\417193\Desktop\MyShareBatch\MyShareOuts'

foreach ($dir in (Get-Content $infile)) {
    $outfile = Join-Path $outdir($dir -split '\\')[-1]
    $outfilecsv = $outfile+'.csv'
    $outfilecsv
    Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter *.* -Recurse |
        Select-Object Name,
            @{Name="Owner";Expression={(Get-ACL $_.fullname).Owner}},
            CreationTime,
            @{Name="FileModifiedDate";Expression={$_.LastWriteTime}},
            @{Name="FileAccessedDate";Expression={$_.LastAccessTime}},
            @{Name="Attributes";Expression={$_.Attributes}},
            @{l='ParentPath';e={Split-Path $_.FullName}},
            @{Name="DormantFor(days)";Expression={[int]((Get-Date)-$_.LastWriteTime).TotalDays}},
            @{Name="Size";Expression={if($_.PSIsContainer -eq $True){(New-Object -com  Scripting.FileSystemObject).GetFolder( $_.FullName).Size} else {$_.Length}}} |
        Export-Csv -Path 

    $outfilecsv -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using switch statement?

```
Function Get-FileSizeCategory( $Object ){
    if( $Object.PSIsContainer ){
        $Length = (New-Object -ComObject Scripting.FileSystemObject).GetFolder($Object.FullName).Size
    } else {
        $Length = $_.Length
    }

    switch( $Length ){
        {$_ -le 10KB}  {"Tiny"; break}
        {$_ -le 1MB}   {"Medium"; break}
        {$_ -le 16MB}  {"Large"; break}
        {$_ -le 128MB} {"Huge"; break}
        default        {"Gigantic"}
    }
}
```

And if you are using Powershell 3.0 or better, you can construct your object by casting a hash to `PSCustomObject` type:

```
$FileList = ls $Dir -Recurse -Filter *.* | Foreach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $_.Name;
        Owner = (Get-Acl $_.FullName).Owner;
        Category = (Get-FileSizeCategory $_);
        # Other properties here
        # ...
    }
}

$FileList | Export-Csv $CsvPath -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ascii
```

Comment: i try to use first solution as follow.@{Name="FileCategory";Expression={Get-FileSizeCategory if($_.PSIsContainer -eq $True){(New-Object -com  Scripting.FileSystemObject).GetFolder( $_.FullName).Length}} .    It thrown error like key "expression" has illegal type  system.object[] ;expected type are system.string,system. management.automation.string block[]. what mistake i have do with above code?? please helop

Comment: Add the check whether the object is folder of not inside Get-FileSizeCategory. See updated answer.

Comment: Yea worked , now when i run from locally. but when i execute the same srom remote server, its not getting updated.  what will be the reason

Comment: that would be another question that I don't know the answer because I only use Powershell locally.